# How to show page numbers in Word document starting from specific page?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, page-numbers

I'm using `Microsoft Word 2016`.

I have a document. Paging starts from first page, but I need to show pages in footer only starting from specific page.

I mean all pages are numerated, but page numbers are visible only after some specific page (for example starting from 10-th page). Previous page numbers are not shown in footer.

---

How to do it in MS Word 2016 without separating into two documents?

Comment: Use a section break and start page numbers from 10 in the new section.

Comment: Does not work. I started paging from page 10 in section 2. It is OK. But previous page numbers in section 1 are visible. I turned off paging in section 1 but it also turned off paging for section 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the document to two sections using section break. By default, headers and footers from the first section are reused for the next section, so you'll need to then uncheck the `Header & Footer Tools -> Design -> Navigation -> Link to Previous` toggle button (this is in the contextual ribbon tab opened when you double-click on a header or footer). This will split the footers to two different instances, and after that you can edit the second section's one and add the page numbers just there.